# Using batch normalization with dropout in test phase gives Nan

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

I am trying to add batch normalization to my CNN and have read a lot of posts about how to do so but still **my implementation yields an array of nans as a result when setting training to False.**

**When setting training to True even on test time, results are not Nan but they are worse than on training time** if I test on training images.

I used a **decay of 0.9** and trained on **15 000 iterations**

Here is my graph building, adding update ops as a dependency as recommended in [tf.layers.batch_normalization documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) and then using sess

```
extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
  with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
    phase_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')

    ###### Other placeholders and variables declarations ######

    # Build a Graph that computes the logits predictions from the inference model.

    loss, eval_prediction = inference(train_data_node, train_labels_node, batch_size, phase_train, dropout_out_keep_prob)

    # Build a Graph that trains the model with one batch of examples and updates the model parameters.

    ###### Should I rather put the dependency here ? ######
    train_op = train(loss, global_step)

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())

    with tf.Session() as sess:
          init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
          sess.run(init)

          # Start the queue runners.
          coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
          threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

          for step in range(startstep, startstep + max_steps):
            feed_dict = fill_feed_dict(train_labels_node, train_data_node, dropout_out_keep_prob, phase_train, batch_size, phase_train_val=True,drop_out_keep_prob_val=1.)
            _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

here is my **batch_norm function call**:

```
def batch_norm_layer(inputT, is_training, scope):
    return tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputT, training=is_training, center=False, reuse=None, momentum=0.9)
```

and now here is how I restore the model for **testing**:

```
phase_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')

###### Other placeholder definitions ######

loss, logits = inference(test_data_node, test_labels_node, batch_size, phase_train, drop_out_keep_prob)
pred = tf.argmax(logits, dimension=3)

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess, test_ckpt)

  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

  feed_dict = fill_feed_dict(test_labels_node, test_data_node, drop_out_keep_prob, phase_train, batch_size=1, phase_train_val=False, drop_out_keep_prob_val=1.)

  pred_loss, dense_prediction, predicted_image = sess.run([loss, logits, pred], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Here dense_prediction gives an array of Nans and thus predicted_image is all 0
Is there an error in my construction ? How can I fix it / diagnose it ?

Any help would be welcome, I have read a lot of tutorials to use "hand made" batch norm but I couldn't find a well guided tutorial on how to use the official batch norm, guess it is because it's too obvious, but it's not for me !

Comment: When you call `extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)`, the graph hasn't been constructed yet, so it is an empty collection. You never actually update the batchnorm variables.

Comment: ok so if I replace with     
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
      extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
      with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops): 
then it should work ?

Comment: No. You should first call `inference`. That function builds part of the graph. Then you get the extra update ops, and construct the training op with the update ops as control dependencies.

Comment: You haven't quite understood how TF works. It is a bit counterintuitive. Hint: it is a gigantic state machine.

Comment: ok, so I have added it just before the train_op = train(loss, global_step) and its the only thing in the with statement and this still gives nans

Comment: yes I will read more about how it works inside !

Comment: Post your complete code, reduced as much as you can while still presenting the issue.

Comment: Here you are, thank you for your patience. I have deleted all summery stuff and other layers details, tell me if something is missing

Comment: Ok so I removed the dropout layer and now it works ! So there must be a conflict coming from this point... I'm searching if there's a way to make them compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem was coming from the fact that I was using **batch normalization** along with **tf.nn.dropout** dropout implementation.

Switching to **tf.layers.dropout** solved the issue.

Comment: Can anybody explain why this may actually cause this NaN problem? Thanks.